# ToLongDateString() not working

Tags: c#, datetime-format

```
string[] splitDate = DateOfBirth.ToLongDateString().Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' });
foreach (string s in splitDate)
{
    Console.Write(s);
}
```

For input like `"15/08/1991"`,  it gives the output `"Thursday August 15 1991"` on my machine but gives output `"August 15 1991"` on another machine.

The code works fine on my system but fails on another system due to above reason. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably your machines have different current thread cultures..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens, because:

> The string returned by the ToLongDateString method is culture-sensitive

as it is stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx).

In order you fix it you have to specify the `CurrentCulture` property of the `CurrentTread`.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("...");
```

However, that will affect everything that relies on the culture in your code.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx) is a list of predefined cultures, that you could use.

Comment: Can we convert `ToLongDateString` to `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal No, you can't. `ToLongDateString()` method uses `D` _standart date and time format_ of `CurrentCulture`. You have to do it manually like `.ToString("D", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: Christos. Please mention Soner's comment in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Soner's comment is correct. Check out the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongtimestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on how to set the culture using [CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx). However, from your code it seems that you just need a string that contains a date and you can do that easily with DateOfBirth.Day, DateOfBirth.Month, DateOfBirth.DayOfWeek etc.

Answer (score 0):

that is because of the culture and region settings of windows.
if u want to do it you can specify the culture you want to use as parameter.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

you can specify your date format as a second parameter as well :)

Comment: But your code doesn't generate `"D"` format which uses by `ToLongDateString()` method. `.ToString(IFormatProvider)` overload generates `"G"` formats output using the short date pattern plus the long time pattern. That means result will be; `"d"` format + `"T"` format.

Comment: Tony: sorry bro "region" :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but this will be helpful for someone stil searching:

```
var CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture; //Store the current culture
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("el-GR"); //Set a new culture
String FullString = MyDate.ToLongDateString(); //Get your string                       
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CurrentCulture; //Restore the environment.
```

Hope this helps.